# Products filter in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this html with jquery , filter the products , by price and category , 
its working when I filter the products by each one seprates but, when I use the both filter price and category its get confused

Can someone help me.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <style>
    ul {list-style:none}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <ul id="shop">
        <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-cat="fruit" data-name="Apple" data-price="1.22">Apple $1.22</a></li>
        <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-cat="fruit" data-name="Banana" data-price="1.33">Banana $1.33</a></li>
        <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-cat="fruit" data-name="Lemon" data-price="22.33">Lemon $22.33</a></li>
        <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-cat="fruit" data-name="Orange" data-price="5.22">Orange $5.22</a></li>

        <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-cat="vegs" data-name="Cucumber" data-price="5.28">Cucumber $5.28</a></li>
        <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-cat="vegs" data-name="Lettuce" data-price="5.12">Lettuce $5.12</a></li>
        <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-cat="vegs" data-name="Tomato" data-price="4.22">Tomato $4.22</a></li>
        <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-cat="vegs" data-name="Mentha" data-price="2.52">Mentha $2.52</a></li>

        <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-cat="drink" data-name="Milk" data-price="1.28">Milk $1.28</a></li>
        <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-cat="drink" data-name="Watar" data-price="2.12">Watar $2.12</a></li>
        <li><a class="add-to-cart" href="#" data-cat="drink" data-name="Joce" data-price="3.22">Joce $3.22</a></li>

    </ul>

    <form action="">
        <input id="fruit" type="checkbox" name="fruit" value="Fruit">Fruit
        <input id="vegs" type="checkbox" name="vigs" value="Vigs">Vegs
        <input id="drink" type="checkbox" name="vigs" value="Vigs">Drink
        Price : From <input id="price-from" type="text" name="price-from" value=""> 
                To <input id="price-to" type="text" name="price-to" value="">
    </form>


    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('#price-to').change(function(){
                $('li a[data-price]').each(function(){
                var filterPriceFrom = $('#price-from').val();
                var filterPriceTo = $('#price-to').val();
                var price = Number($(this).attr("data-price"));
                if(price >= filterPriceFrom && price <= filterPriceTo){

                    if($(this).css('display') == 'none'){$(this).hide();}
                    else{$(this).show();}

                }
                else{
                    $(this).hide();
                }
             });
            });



            $('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function() {
                if ($('input[type="checkbox"]').is(':checked')) {

                    $('li a[data-cat]').hide();
                    $('input[type="checkbox"]').each(function() {
                        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                            var att = $(this).attr('id');
                            var sel = 'li a[data-cat="' + att + '"]';

                            $(sel).show();

                        } else {
                            $(sel).hide();
                        }
                    });

                } else {
                    $('li a[data-cat]').show()
                }
            });

        });
    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have not looked into this a ton, but something that jumps out right away is the if ($("input[type='checkbox']).is(":checked")) will not function properly if you have more than 1 checkbox. You need to change that line to if ($(this).is(":checked")) to get an accurate representation of the checkbox that actually triggered the event handler

Comment: the checkboxes are working fine , but when i use the textfiled filter with it  its ignore the checkbox filter and take the filter only from textfiled

Comment: Why the question downvotes? It is a clear, answerable question, that includes what the author has tried, specifically what did not work, and includes code to recreate a minimal example to replicate the problem the author is facing... That meets every good question criteria for this site...

Comment: its because of some people they dont know how to solve it or they dont want to read it , they just want very easy questions to solve it then they will voteup ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here: This is exactly what you need. Your code needed quite a bit of restructuring, but here you go.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var filterType = [];
    var filterPriceFrom;
    var filterPriceTo;

    function applyFilters() {
      filterPriceFrom = Number($('#price-from').val());
      filterPriceTo = Number($('#price-to').val());
      filterType = [];
      $("input[type='checkbox']:checked").each(function () {
        filterType.push($(this).attr("id"));
      });
      $("li a").hide();
      $("li a").each(function (){
        var price = Number($(this).attr("data-price"));

        if ((price >= filterPriceFrom && price <= filterPriceTo) || (filterPriceFrom === 0 && filterPriceTo === 0)){
          if (!filterType.length || filterType.indexOf($(this).attr("data-cat")) > -1) {
            $(this).show();
          }
        }
      });
    }

    $('#price-to, input[type="checkbox"]').change(function(){
      applyFilters();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Thanks so much , you are expert